# Truthy and falsey value (jQuery object)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing a function to check/uncheck radio buttons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="">
             <input type="radio"  name="sex" value="male" checked>Male<br>
             <input type="radio"  name="sex" value="female">Female
        </form>

        <script src = "../javascript/defaultCheckRadio.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code is doing the job, but I do not understand why the alert in the if block is never triggered. In my understanding, it should be triggered because all jQuery objects are truthy.

```
(function () {

    var inElement = $('input');

    var changeCheck = {
        init: function () {
              this.check();
        }, 

        check: function () {

            $.each(inElement, function() {
                var self = $(this); 
                if (self.checked) {
                    alert("if condition");
                    self.prop('checked',false);
                } else {
                    alert("else");
                    self.prop('checked',true);
                    } 
            });
        },
    };

    window.changeCheck = changeCheck.init();
})();
```

Comment: `$(this).checked` is `undefined`, because `checked` is not a jQuery method (or  a property of the jQuery object), so `self.checked` is falsy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your if wrong, you are checking a javascript property on a jquery object, You should change:

```
if (self.checked) {
```

to:

```
if (self.prop('checked')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Just forget about jQuery and use vanilla-js:

```js
if (this.checked) {
    alert("if condition");
    this.checked = false;
} else {
    alert("else");
    this.checked = true;
}
```

Note it can be simplified:

```js
alert((this.checked = !this.checked) ? "else" : "if condition");
```